# Date from datepicker two lines

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I used datepicker, but when my date is showing, i would like it to be in two lines.

Like
Instead of having that:

```
December 12
```

Having that:

```
December
12
```

Bellow my datepicker settings

```
    $( "#end-date" ).datepicker({
                minDate: new Date(),
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
                altFormat: "d MM",
                altField: "#alt-date-end", 
                monthNames: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Janv.', 'Févr.', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil.', 'Août', 'Sept.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Déc.'],
                dayNames: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dim.', 'Lun.', 'Mar.', 'Mer.', 'Jeu.', 'Ven.', 'Sam.'],
                dayNamesMin: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S'],
                weekHeader: 'Sem.',
    });
```

Maybe altFormat or altField is the solution? But don't know how to take separately month and date

Comment: what is different in both ?

Comment: One is in one line, the other has the month and bellow the day. Like a <br> between month and day..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about this plugin, but try adding `\n` which is a newline character, and see if it works

```
$( "#end-date" ).datepicker({
    // (...) more properties
    altFormat: "d\nMM" // new line added
});
```

Comment: @colinec try using `"d<br/>MM"`

Comment: I tried it but still doesn't work. It shows : December<br/>31